# why can pumping lemma for PDA be pumped down?

Tags: pumping-lemma

1. for each `i ≥ 0`, `uv^ixy^iz ∈ A,`
2. `|vy| > 0`, and
3. `|vxy| ≤ p`.

for 2, if we pump down uvxyz, we got uxz, but it will violate 2. since |vy| = 0.

I saw this as example at lots of place, where did i understand wrongly?

Comment: what does ^ stand for ?

Comment: repeat v and y for i times i believe. sorry for not making it clear

Answer (score 2):

Ok i got this. 
After a second thought, I think it meancs |vy| is non empty string, yet when they are pumped down, they repeat 0 times which make them disappear, but v y themselves are not defined empty.

Sorry for the stupid question.